# How to play video in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, video

How to play a video in Java Swing? Is there any Swing components for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at FMJ - http://fmj-sf.net/

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this will solve your problem : [How to use JVLC (Java bindings for VLC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127587/how-to-use-jvlc-java-bindings-for-vlc)

Comment: The link given on the above post is DEAD. Did you mean http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/ .

Comment: @asela38 - I mistakenly edited your post. Just made a rollback. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is JMF (Java Media Framework).

You can find some tutorials on how to use it in the SO question below.

[where can i find Java JMF tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402459/where-can-i-find-java-jmf-tutorial)

Comment: Note that JMF has been sadly neglected by Sun.  It may be hard to find the appropriate codecs.

Comment: Agree with above comment. Two days I was trying a simple .mov file and it failed miserably. Although FMJ looks good as of now.

Comment: This would be a nice concise answer, except that it is apparently sadly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

vlcj is a very nice library for playing video in Java Swing, but it needs to have VLC installed on user's computer first:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj